constrained Delaunay triangulation algorithm starting, not ending, with constraints
Let $X$ be a collection of points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $\Omega$ be a triangulation of the input point set.
A triangle $\{x_i, x_j, x_k\}$ encroaches on the point $x_l$ if $x_l$ is in the interior of the unique circle passing through all vertices of the triangle.
The triangulation is Delaunay if no triangle encroaches on any other point of the input set.
Let $\Gamma$ be a planar straight-line graph on the input point set, i.e. a collection of pairs of vertices $\gamma = (x_i, x_j)$ representing edges, e.g. the boundary of a domain.
The triangle $\{x_i, x_j, x_k\}$ is positively-oriented if
$$\text{signed volume}(x_i, x_j, x_k) \equiv \det\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ x_i & x_j & x_k\end{matrix}\right] > 0.$$
The point $x_l$ is visible to the edge $\{x_j, x_k\}$ of a positively-oriented triangle if the signed volume of $x_j, x_k, x_l$ is negative.
A triangulation $\Omega$ is constrained Delaunay if

Every edge of $\Gamma$ is in some triangle of $\Omega$
For every (positively-oriented) triangle $\{x_i, x_j, x_k\}$ of $\Omega$ and every other input point $x_l$, the triangle does not encroach on $x_l$, or the edge $\{x_j, x_k\}$ that $x_l$ is visible to is in the constraint graph $\Gamma$.

Constrained Delaunay triangulations are usually used to produce nice finite element meshes that respect a possible non-convex domain boundary, holes, etc.
Intuitively they are "as Delaunay as possible" given the constraints.
Every algorithm that I've come across for computing the constrained Delaunay triangulation proceeds by (1) computing the unconstrained Delaunay triangulation of $X$ and then (2) incrementally adding each edge $\gamma$ of $\Gamma$.
Some algorithms add the constrained edges by doing a sequence of edge flips, others by removing the crossing edges and re-triangulating the resulting polygonal cavity; the means isn't important.
Is there any constrained Delaunay triangulation algorithm that instead starts with all the constrained edges and incrementally adds triangles to it?
I've never seen one.
It sort of sounds harder but I can't think of some fundamental reason why it should be.
The closest thing I can find, which is still not what I'm looking for, is Chew (1987) -- this is really a divide-and-conquer algorithm though.
References I've consulted: [1], [2], [3], [4], [5].

Can you outline what "constrained Delaunay algorithm" means, and how the edges of the graph enter into the triangulation.

Hi Wolfang, I've added some definitions.
